# Язык C. Даны N предложений. Найти в каждом последнее слово и напечатать их в строку через пробел

Tags: c

Я попытался сам реализовать, но этот код, пишет только последнее слово последнего предложения, а должно было быть, чтобы выводило все последние слова

Код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
// #include <stdbool.h>

#define TEXT_SIZE_MAX 500

int main()
{   
    char text[TEXT_SIZE_MAX+1];
    
    int lenght;
    printf("Введите предложение через '.'\n");
    fgets(text, TEXT_SIZE_MAX, stdin);
    lenght = strlen(text);
    for (int i = lenght-1; isspace(text[i]); i--){ 
        text[i] = 0;
        --lenght;
    }
    int c = 0;
   
    for (int i = lenght-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(isspace(text[i])){
           c = i + 1;
           break;
        }
    }
    for (int i = c; i < lenght; i++)
        putchar( (text[i] != '.') ? text[i] : '\0');
    
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Вот Ваш "сам попытался"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1243751/248924). Вообще, плагиат как-то не приветствуется в обществе. И поскольку Вы решили **присвоить** себе чужой код, то я не стану, и призываю других не помогать в этом вопросе.

Comment: @Vladimir в принципе можно и засудить за нарушение Creative Commons)

Comment: @Vladimir Я добавил данный код не в целях выдать его за свой, а дабы пользователям было удобнее работать не с сырым материалом. С тем, кому вы отвечали я учусь в одном учебном заведении и выполняем одно практическое задание.

Comment: В каком это смысле сказать правду стало оскорблением? Вы можете доказать, что я Вас оклеветал? Я не вижу смысла в какой-либо дискуссии. Если вдруг Вы решите, что таки не Вы это писали, а просто позаимствовали у коллеги (которому я отвечал и который честно приложил свою попытку решить проблему), тогда и никаких вопросов с моей стороны не будет. И перечитайте еще раз правила сообщества - там сказано, чтобы вопрошающий выкладывал свою попытку решения, а не заимствованную, выданную за свою.